# date formatting using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am trying to format the dates using `date-fns` as my desired format. My attempt is as in below.

```
export function getFormattedDistanceToNow(date) {
 const options = {
   locale: {
    ...enUS,
    formatDistance: (unit, count) => {
      switch (true) {
        case unit === 'xDays':
          return `${count} d`;

        case unit === 'xHours':
          return `${count} h`;

        case unit === 'xMinutes':
          return `${count} min`;

        case unit === 'xMonths':
          return `${count * 30} d`; // 30 is correct?

        case unit === 'xSeconds':
          return 'just now';

        case unit === 'xYears':
          return `${count * 365} d`; // 365 is correct?
      }

      return '%d hours';
    },
   },
 };

 return formatDistanceToNowStrict(date, options);
}
```

When `switch case` meets the criteria of `xMonths`, I need to show it in days. So I multiply the count by 30. Is that correct always? Because some months can have 31 days, 28 days as well. Also when it meets `xYears`, I multiplied the count by 365 despite having 366 days for some years. Is that also correct? I am a bit confused about it. Or else is there any better way to do it using `date-fns`?